How does one find distinct signals in FFT transform log that have been produced by different transmitters?
I would like to separate signals found in my FFT transform, leaving only those I am interested in, say a digital transmitter. But in my area, there are hundreds of wifi routers, drones, large airport nearby. Some of these devices are using overlapping frequencies and freq hopping. What are the techniques or software tools in FFT for isolating a signal transmitter and tracing its channels?

What you're looking for is called source separation. There's many techniques for that, with different methods requiring different amount of knowledge on statistics and other properties of the different sources.
It's not generally possible to do that with just any amount of unknown signals, and especially impossible to do after the mixture signal has already been reduced to its magnitude after an FFT. So "in FFT" is not what you can work in. I think you're assuming this to be simpler than it is: You're really asking something that is equivalent "I have the sum of two (or more) numbers, it's 63.12, what were the two (or more) numbers?", and without making many assumptions about how the two (or more) numbers came to be, you can't resolve that sum.
In the case of known overlapping Wifi channels, these having exactly the same statistics, you can, at best, just hope you get some observations, build a software receiver for Wifi frames, estimate the channel based on the observed pilots and preambles, and then follow a successive interferance cancellation scheme until you identified most of the wifi stations. This will in general not work, and assumes you have a very advantageous position relative to the emitters.
In short: what you want to do is impossible, there's some methods which, under extensive understanding of the individual signals, can resolve overlapping signals, but even that's a very challenging problem.
Maybe you want to use multiple coherent receive chains, with an antenna array, and do direction finding instead? That's (part of) what commercial drone finding companies do.

Thank you Marcus. I did suspect my problem was intractable in general case, exactly as you described once the signals overlap it is impossible to establish what led to them. And yes, I was also wondering what commercial or open source packages do to resolve signal source.
I forgot to mention. I read some of your other answers and was hoping someone of your caliber sees my silly inquiry. Thank you so much for taking the time to respond.
